# Arrays.copyOfRange method in java throws incorrect exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, try-catch

I was working on arrays today and suddenly I came across a scenario throwing unexpected exceptions.

If you look at the code below , I think it must throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but surprisingly it is throwing `IllegalArgumentException` instead:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RangeTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 10);
    // If we'll use Integer.MIN_VALUE+100 instead Integer.MIN_VALUE,
    // OutOfMemoryError will be thrown
    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
        System.out.print(b[k] + " ");
   }
}
```

Can anybody help me and let me know if I am mistaken?

Comment: The comment in your code section says `OutOfMemoryError`. Did you mean `IllegalArgumentException`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the Javadoc says :

> **Throws:**
>
> - **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** - if from < 0 or from > original.length
> - **IllegalArgumentException** - if from > to

Looking at the implementation, you can see that you got an `IllegalArgumentException` exception instead of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to `int` overflow :

```
public static int[] copyOfRange(int[] original, int from, int to) {
    int newLength = to - from;
    if (newLength < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
    int[] copy = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

This code thinks that `from` > `to` because `to-from` caused int overflow (due to `from` being `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), which resulted in a negative `newLength`.

Comment: Thanks @Eran any suggestions to handle in my code , should I catch it and re throw as indexoutofbound....asking because seems you are veteran in java more then 131K reputation....awesome SIR :)

Comment: @ShowStopper Why would you ever pass a negative `from` to that method? You shouldn't catch exceptions that you can prevent from being thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You send Integer.MIN_VALUE(-2147483648) as from range.
You probably meant to send 0 instead

Answer (score 2):

You face error as MIN_VALUE = -2147483648 [0x80000000] which is negative. either u set 0 i.e. `Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, 10);` . it will allowed you to copy.

Answer (score 1):

There is miss match between java Docs and implementation

As expalained by Eran we can see that we got an IllegalArgumentException exception instead of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException due to int overflow .