# What is the logic behind Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[], int, int) strange behavior?

Tags: java, arrays, standard-library

Can anyone explain me the logic behind strange behavior of  [Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[], int, int))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-)? I can illustrate what I mean with simple example:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1, 1, 1};
Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 3, 4); // Returns single element (0) array
Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 4, 5); // Throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

In both cases I copy ranges **outside of array boundaries** (i.e. `start >= array.length`), so the condition for error is at least strange for me (if `from < 0` or `from > original.length`). In my opinion it should be: if `from < 0` or `from >= original.length`. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34508006/2310289

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays.copyOfRange method in java throws incorrect exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507935/arrays-copyofrange-method-in-java-throws-incorrect-exception)

Comment: The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and original.length, inclusive

Comment: Both throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (in Java 8). `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3 > 1`

Comment: To [Kayman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman) - in my case it's single element array, as I wrote.

Comment: More interestingly, `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 2, 4)` returns `[1, 0]`. Java 8_65

Comment: To [SubOptimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333222/suboptimal) - the first case doesn't result in error, again as I wrote. And I'm on:

    openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: To [Zeflick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865757/zefick) - it's expected behavior (read javadoc about padding).

Comment: To [UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep) -  just read the original question (I completely understand that, I just don't get the logic behind it). In both cases I copy range **outside of array boundaries**.

Comment: Considering how strict Java is usually, I find the zero-padding a bit exceptional.

Comment: This behavior seems to be consistent with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte[],%20int,%20int)). `from` must be not greater than `original.length`. However, one would expect that `from` must not be greater than `original.length - 1`.

Comment: [MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507738/mc-emperor), yep - but I don't get the logic behind this.

Comment: @IvanSharamet Now (after you edited your question) the behaviour is as you wrote.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the [technote that announced the introduction of these methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes6.html)

Answer (score 5):

[The JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-) specifies three points regarding the arguments it expects:

One:

> [**from**] *must* lie between **zero** and **original.length**, inclusive

Two:

> [**to**] *must* be greater than or equal to **from**

Three:

> [**to**] may be greater than **original.length**

For the case of `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 3, 4)` one, two and three are true which means they are valid.

For the case of `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 4, 5)` only two and three are true which means they are invalid.

---

Expected behaviour? Yes.

*Unintuitive* behaviour? Kinda.

If your question is secretly "*why* was it designed this way?" then no one can tell you the answer except the code authors.

Answer (score 0):

Look, how copyOfRange works:

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    int newLength = to - from;
    if (newLength < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

The most important part is this:

```
System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
```

So when you're calling Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 3, 4); the last param of  System.arraycopy "length - the number of array elements to be copied" is 0. The call of arraycopy looks like System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,0);

Comment: Well, justifying bad API with internal implementation is strange, and even stranger when we're a talking about standard library.

Comment: Also pls check when System.arraycopy throws IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
The srcPos argument is negative.
The destPos argument is negative.
The length argument is negative.
srcPos+length is greater than src.length, the length of the source array.
destPos+length is greater than dest.length, the length of the destination array

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the source of [Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3510)

```
  public static byte[] copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to) {
1     int newLength = to - from;
2     if (newLength < 0)
3         throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
4     byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];
5     System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
6                      Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
7     return copy;
  }
```

- at line 1 the length of the destination array is computed with `1`
- at line 4 the new array is created with size `1`, all elements are `0`
- at line 6 the length of the element to be copied is computed as zero, because

  ```
  // Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
  Math.min(3 - 3, 1)); --> returns zero
  ```
- at line 5 the `System.arraycopy` simply does not copy anything into array `copy`

If your `from` is `bytes.length + 1` then `length` get negative (bytes.length - from).

A small code to demonstrate

```
public class ArrayCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{11, 12, 13};
        int from = 3;
        int to = 4;
        copyOfRange(bytes, from, to);

        from = 2;
        to = 3;
        copyOfRange(bytes, from, to);

        from = 4;
        to = 5;
        copyOfRange(bytes, from, to);
    }

    static void copyOfRange(byte[] bytes, int from, int to) {
        System.out.printf("%ncopyOfRange(bytes: %s  from: %d  to: %d)%n",
                Arrays.toString(bytes),
                from,
                to
                );

        // line 1
        int newLength = to - from;
        System.out.println("int newLength = " + newLength);

        // line 2
        if (newLength < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
        }

        // line 4
        byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];

        // to show that in the suspicious case System.arrayCopy does nothing
        copy[0] = 42;
        System.out.println("byte[] copy   = " + Arrays.toString(copy));
        int length = bytes.length - from;
        System.out.println("int length    = " + length);
        int minLenght = Math.min(length, newLength);
        System.out.println("int minLenght = " + minLenght);

        // line 5
        System.arraycopy(bytes, from, copy, 0, minLenght);

        System.out.println("byte[] copy   = " + Arrays.toString(copy));
    }
}
```

output

```
copyOfRange(bytes: [11, 12, 13]  from: 3  to: 4)
int newLength = 1
byte[] copy   = [42]
int length    = 0
int minLenght = 0
byte[] copy   = [42]

copyOfRange(bytes: [11, 12, 13]  from: 2  to: 3)
int newLength = 1
byte[] copy   = [42]
int length    = 1
int minLenght = 1
byte[] copy   = [13]

copyOfRange(bytes: [11, 12, 13]  from: 4  to: 5)
int newLength = 1
byte[] copy   = [42]
int length    = -1
int minLenght = -1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are able to create new "empty" Array of any length using this method like you described for `// Returns single element (0) array` situation.

The main purpose why `Arrays.copyOfRange` method exist, is because it create new Array "on the fly". And this new Array can be bigger than source Array, of course.

That behavior is a [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte[],%20int,%20int)) feature.

> **The final index of the range (to)**, which must be greater than or equal to from, **may be greater than original.length**, in which case
>   '\u000' is placed in all elements of the copy whose index is greater
>   than or equal to original.length - from. The length of the returned
>   array will be to - from.

Why it's implemented like this? Assuming you are going to invoke this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1, 1, 1};
byte[] newBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 2, 6); // Returns array length 6 - 2 = 4
```

It will create array [1, 0, 0, 0] and all elements which are not exist in original array will be initialized by default literal for current type. **But** if you want to specify `from` is bigger but not equals `bytes.length` (which is discouraged by documentation) it will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` during invoking this `System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));` because `original.length - from` will be less than `0`.

So technically saying if you use such instructions:

```
int n = 4;
Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, bytes.length, bytes.length + n);
```

assumes you just want to create new empty Array of size `n`. In other words, you are creating a new Array and copy nothing from source Array.